# PHP Rewrite URL or Mask or Redirect?

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get domain.com/employee?display_county=sd&dept=sales&id=23 to display in the URL as domain.com/firstnamelastname while retaining the URL variables.
And also if someone goes directly to domain.com/firstnamelastname it would still have the original URL variables.

How would one accomplish this?

Edit: OK, so I'm starting to rethink this...
Let's say I have a page that displays a list of users.
Each user has a clickable link that directs to domain.com/employee?display_county=XX&dept=XXXXX&id=XX

How could I get the URL to display domain.com/firstnamelastname when a user is clicked and still bring up the correct user?

I was thinking maybe using a POST method to pass the id to the script that displays the user and then rewriting the URL to display the firstnamelastname related to the id, but then browsing directly to domain.com/firstnamelastname would leave the id variable empty...

Comment: ok great .. so the question would be?

Comment: To display where?

Comment: Are you using Apache? If so, look into `mod_rewrite`. It's relatively trivial to set a rewriterule that interprets `/firstnamelastname` as `/employee?display_county=sd&dept=sales&id=23` **Edit**: Assuming those variables never change, of course.

Comment: you can't have it both ways if var X is not in the url, you dont have var X in the url. you will have to look up display_county,dept,id based on what you do have in the url

Comment: I think you got how Apache (not PHP) rewrite works backwards, you don't convert the URL 'on the fly', you use `domain.com/firstnamelastname` as the link and then configure the server so when the browser request that URL Apache internally serves `domain.com/employee?display_county=XX&dept=XXXXX&id=XX`. Maybe you could do it using [`RewriteMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html).